# iOS Swift UIDatePicker inline style time and days title not display when set on inputView

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, inputaccessoryview

I use `inline` `UIDatePicker` with `dateAndTime` mode as `inputView` for `TextField`.  However, it not display time and days title. Like below image.

[image]

Below are my code for set `UIDatePicker`:-

```
    func setupDatePicker() {
        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker?.date = Date()
        datePicker?.locale = .current
        datePicker?.minimumDate = Date()
        datePicker?.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            datePicker?.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        }
        datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDateSelection), for: .valueChanged)
        
        txtDate.inputView = datePicker
    }
```

Please help me how to show time and days title in this like below.

[image]]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you inspected your view hierarchy to find out, whether the time label is rendered at least somewhere? Maybe it's not visible for a reason. Because I tried your code and it worked for me as expected. Also, do you have your output in iOS 14+ or earlier? For me, time is not displayed without `.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline`.

Comment: Yes I tried with iOS 15 but not work for me.  Can you set datepicker as inputView?

Comment: that's a custom picker which you will need to search for...

Comment: @FahimParkar That's not a custom picker it's default picker.

Comment: you want to add days... right? if yes, default don't have there... you have to make custom for that...

Comment: @ChiragKothiya did you find any solutions? Currently I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Hilaj No, I haven't find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for this. The idea is to wrap UIDatePicker inside of another UIView which frame provides enough space to display entire UIDatePicker. Then use auto-layouts for UIDatePicker to snap edges to the superview or just update the frame to match superview.

Code snippet:

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()

// Your additional code to set up `UIDatePicker`

if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
}

// Big enough frame
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 420)
let pickerWrapperView = UIView(frame: rect)
pickerWrapperView.addSubview(picker)

// Adding constraints
picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerWrapperView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerWrapperView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
picker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerWrapperView.topAnchor).isActive = true
picker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerWrapperView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

// Using wrapper view instead of picker
textField.inputView = pickerWrapperView
```